# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED trying to validate a reCAPTCHA with django

Tags: python, django, ssl, kubernetes, recaptcha

I'm getting a

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>
```

When I try to validate captchas in my django project.
This is how i do it:

```py
  recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
  print(recaptcha_response)
  url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
  values = {
      'secret': settings.CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
      'response': recaptcha_response
  }
  data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
  req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(req) # It fails here
  result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
  print(result)
```

The site has a valid certificate, and it works on local. In the log i'm getting this:

Request Method: POST

Request URL:    http://prod.xxxx.com/evalua

Which is weird because the site works in https. Its on kubernetes, could that be the problem? I really have no idea what the problem IS? I have the captcha keys correctly set up in de recaptcha admin console. And the certificate are not autosign. I use lets encrypt

Answer (score 0):

Check how you build the container image for your app and if it has very old CA certificates in it. You can use something like `ADD https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` to ensure you have the latest standard bundle. You can also switch to Requests and Certifi instead of urllib, as that embeds a copy of the current cert bundle and ensures it is used.